# AlertDialog с EditText: автоматическое появление клавиатуры

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-inputmethodmanager

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        });
        alert.show();

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Я создаю АлертДиалогОкно с полем для ввода. Надо, чтобы сразу появлялась клавиатура, но она не появляется. 
Я понимаю, что ошибка в `showSoftInput` и там должен быть не `input`, а именно часть из уже созданного AlertDialog. Как ее получить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно для начала перевести фокус на нужное view, в нашем случае editText и далее вызвать для него клавиатуру.
Вот такой метод можно использовать:

```
protected void showSoftInput(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (view != null) {
            view.post(() -> {
                view.requestFocus();
                inputManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
            });
        }
    }
```